# How to read and print the line multiple strings appear on in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a log file with contents in this format:

```
[28/Feb/2017] 00007bd2 7d194700 - ERROR: ws_common: 
[28/Feb/2017] 00007bd2 7d194700 - ERROR: ESI: getResponse: failed 
[28/Feb/2017] 00007bd2 DOWN- [] ws_common:
```

I want to find and print the line containing a keyword like "DOWN", as well as the time the message appears in the log file.

I did it like this in UNIX:

```
SomeVariable =`cat $filename| grep "$DD/$MTH/$YR:$HR:$MINM" | grep DOWN | wc -l
```

but I can't seem to get it right in Ruby. This returns ALL of the lines as well as the line numbers:

```
File.foreach("#{filename}").with_index do |line, line_num|

  if File.open("#{filename}") { |f| f.each.find { |line| line.include?("#
          {DAY}/#{MTH}/#{YR}:#{HR}:#{MINM}" && "down") }  }

    puts "#{line_num}: #{line} "
  end
end
```

Using the file above as an example, the output I would like to get from this is:

3 [28/Feb/2017] 00007bd2 DOWN- [] ws_common:

"3" being the third line.

Comment: please share the expected string output

Comment: You open, read and iterate the file N+1 times (or so it looks). I'm surprised you're not _flooded_ by output.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need to know what your expected output should be.

Comment: On a side note `line.include?("#{DAY}/#{MTH}/#{YR}:#{HR}:#{MINM}" && "down")` is only looking for `"down"`. Reason being is that you are not saying look for `"#{DAY}/#{MTH}/#{YR}:#{HR}:#{MINM}"` and `"down"` you are saying look for `"down"` when `"#{DAY}/#{MTH}/#{YR}:#{HR}:#{MINM}"` is truthy (which it always will be). but there are quite a few other issues here as well such as the whole second `File.open` (which is unnecessary) will always be true as well (which is why it prints every line)

Answer (score 3):

> I've done it like this in UNIX:
>
> ```
>  SomeVariable =`cat $filename| grep "$DD/$MTH/$YR:$HR:$MINM" | grep DOWN | wc -l
> ```

And here it's almost the same. This prints all lines with `DOWN` in them.

```
puts File.foreach(filename).grep(/DOWN/)
# >> [28/Feb/2017] 00007bd2 DOWN-
```

I am not sure if you want to *grep* for timestamp or you want to simply know the timestamps of DOWN events. If it's the latter, here you have it (lines are printed in their entirety). If it's the former, it shouldn't be too hard to implement, now that you are armed with this new technique.

Comment: OK to match "DOWNTOWN"? You changed your avatar, so I now see what you look like. Not at all what I imagined. I pictured you as resembling [one of your countrymen](http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01866/ras_1866302b.jpg).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: what do you mean, changed avatar? I didn't. I had this one for a long time. :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: "OK to match "DOWNTOWN"" - presumably, logs like that won't contain DOWNTOWN. But yes, if that's a concern, one is free to decorate the regex with `\b` markers.